# JPA "Friend" relationship between 2 same type entities

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a defined JPA entity which references other entities of the same type with a @ManyToMany relationship.

```
@Entity(name = "GANG")
public class Gang {

  @Getter
  @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Getter
  @Column(name = "DESC", nullable = true)
  private String description;

  @ManyToMany
  private Set<Gang> allies;
}
```

Where "allies" should point to a join table linking two Gangs together. However, with my current understanding of JPA, when this entity is created, and a friend link is created, when recalled, not all links will be returned, since the Gang ID (not displayed in my model, a BINARY(16) UUID), can exist in both columns of the join table.

```
+------------+------------+
|gang_a      |gang_b      |
+------------+------------+
|A           |B           |
+------------+------------+
|C           |A           |
+------------+------------+
```

When I retrieve the friends of gang A, I should receive objects of gang B and gang C. How would I go about linking this relationship?